# Angular 2 passing data from parent component to dynamic modal

Tags: angular, data-binding, bootstrap-modal

I used this example:
[How to dynamically create bootstrap modals as Angular2 components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566698/how-to-dynamically-create-bootstrap-modals-as-angular2-components)
to develop my own plunk with dynamic generation of different or the same modals shared between more components.
Unfortunately I have some difficulties because I don't know how to pass data from parent component to the modals.
In my plunk (https://plnkr.co/edit/RgI1e9PobC7FloLHpEFD?p=preview), the data to pass is called "dataToPass".
Any ideas?

Here below my app.ts:

```
//our root app component
import {
  NgModule, 
  ComponentRef, 
  Injectable, 
  Component, 
  Injector, 
  ViewContainerRef, 
  ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  showModal:Subject<any> = new Subject();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-comp',
  template: `MyComponent`
})
export class CompComponent { }

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
      <button (click)="showDialog()">show modal from child</button>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {}

  showDialog() {
    this.sharedService.showModal.next(CompComponent);
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-comp',
  template: `
  <div class="modal fade" id="theModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="theModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog largeWidth" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="theModalLabel">The Label</h4></div>
        <div class="modal-body" #theBody>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (close)="close()">Close</button>
  </div></div></div></div>
`
})
export class ModalComponent {
  @ViewChild('theBody', {read: ViewContainerRef}) theBody;

  cmp:ComponentRef;

  constructor(
    sharedService:SharedService, 
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, 
    injector: Injector) {

    sharedService.showModal.subscribe(type => {
      if(this.cmpRef) {
        this.cmpRef.destroy();
      }
      let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
      this.cmpRef = this.theBody.createComponent(factory);
      $('#theModal').modal('show');
    });
  }

  close() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }
    this.cmpRef = null;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <button (click)="showDialog()">show modal</button>
      <child-component></child-component>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  private dataToPass: string;
  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {
    this.dataToPass = 'data to pass';
  }

  showDialog() {
    this.sharedService.showModal.next(CompComponent);
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, ModalComponent, CompComponent, ChildComponent],
  providers: [SharedService],
  entryComponents: [CompComponent],
  bootstrap: [ App, ModalComponent ]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone could interest, I was able to find the solution.

I pass the data I need as parameters of `next` function, as Subject can be used to emit values to its subscribers:

```
showDialog() {
    this.sharedService.showModal.next({'type': CompComponent, 'title': 'titolo1', 'dataToPass': 'dataToPass'});
  }
```

Then I passed the data to `CompComponent` inside `subscribe` function (following this example: [Angular 2 Passing data to component when dynamically adding the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243748/angular-2-passing-data-to-component-when-dynamically-adding-the-component)), this way:

```
  let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.type);
  this.cmpRef = this.theBody.createComponent(factory);
  this.cmpRef.instance.dataToPass = data.dataToPass;
```

Here below the whole code, you can see it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/RgI1e9PobC7FloLHpEFD?p=preview) on plunker, too.

```
//our root app component
import {
  NgModule, 
  ComponentRef, 
  Injectable, 
  Component, 
  Injector, 
  ViewContainerRef, 
  ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  showModal:Subject<any> = new Subject();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-comp',
  template: `MyComponent {{dataToPass}}`
})
export class CompComponent { }

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
      <button (click)="showDialog()">show modal from child</button>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {}

  showDialog() {
    this.sharedService.showModal.next({'type': CompComponent, 'title': 'titolo2', 'dataToPass': 'dataToPass'});
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-comp',
  template: `
  <div class="modal fade" id="theModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="theModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog largeWidth" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{theHeader}}</h4></div>
        <div class="modal-body" #theBody>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (close)="close()">Close</button>
  </div></div></div></div>
`
})
export class ModalComponent {
  @ViewChild('theBody', {read: ViewContainerRef}) theBody;

  theHeader: string = '';
  cmpRefBody:ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(
    sharedService:SharedService, 
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, 
    injector: Injector) {

    sharedService.showModal.subscribe(data => {
      if(this.cmpRef) {
        this.cmpRef.destroy();
      }
      let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.type);
      this.cmpRef = this.theBody.createComponent(factory);
      this.cmpRef.instance.dataToPass = data.dataToPass;
      this.theHeader = data.title;
      console.log(data.title);
      console.log(data.dataToPass);
      $('#theModal').modal('show');
    });
  }

  close() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }
    this.cmpRef = null;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <button (click)="showDialog()">show modal</button>
      <child-component></child-component>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {}

  showDialog() {
    this.sharedService.showModal.next({'type': CompComponent, 'title': 'titolo1', 'dataToPass': 'dataToPass'});
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, ModalComponent, CompComponent, ChildComponent],
  providers: [SharedService],
  entryComponents: [CompComponent],
  bootstrap: [ App, ModalComponent ]
})
export class AppModule{}
```